# Error Serving Static Files From SPA - Asp.NET Core with React

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm having asp.net core with React project. It's web API along with a spa application project.
From the spa, I want to be able to serve static files located in the wwwroot folder or from another folder called content from the client app.
Here's my Startup.cs configuration

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseCors();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Content")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Content")
});
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

But Whenever I try to serve any file from both directories like `https://domain/url_to_file`, it gives me `404 file not found`.
Any Idea about what I'm doing wrong here?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEBeu.png)

Comment: Don't forget the 
file extension.Be sure your request should be like below:`https://localhost:44372/content/imageName.jpg`.

Comment: @Rena The file extension is there and the path is completely correct. I guess that ```app.UseSp()``` is used, when calling the static file as a map to the route, because it's giving me the ```404``` react component instead of using ```app.UseStaticFiles()```.